# Prevent QGraphicsItem from moving outside of QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a scene which has fixed dimensions from (0;0) to (481;270):

```
scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 481, 270);
```

Inside of it, I have a custom `GraphicsItem` and I can move it thanks to the flag `ItemisMovable`, but I would like it to stay within the Scene; I actually mean I don't want it to have coordinates neither under (0;0) nor over (481;270).

I tried several solutions like overriding `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()` or even `QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent()` but I still cannot manage to reach what I want to do.

What is the suitable solution for my needs? Do I use `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()` badly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can override `QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent()` like this:

```
YourItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event); // move the item...

    // ...then check the bounds
    if (x() < 0)
        setPos(0, y());
    else if (x() > 481)
        setPos(481, y());

    if (y() < 0)
        setPos(x(), 0);
    else if (y() > 270)
        setPos(x(), 270);
}
```

Comment: Amazing, I tried to insert the parent's method after my checks instead of before... Your solution works fine, thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

This code keeps your complete item in scene. Not only the upper left pixel of your item.

```
void YourItem::mouseMoveEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event )
{
    QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event); 

    if (x() < 0)
    {
        setPos(0, y());
    }
    else if (x() + boundingRect().right() > scene()->width())
    {
        setPos(scene()->width() - boundingRect().width(), y());
    }

    if (y() < 0)
    {
        setPos(x(), 0);
    }
    else if ( y()+ boundingRect().bottom() > scene()->height())
    {
        setPos(x(), scene()->height() - boundingRect().height());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Warning:** The suggested solutions won't work for multiply selected items. The problem is, only one of the items receives a mouse move event in that case.

Actually, the [Qt Documentation on QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) provides an example which exactly solves the problem of limiting the movement of items to the scene rect:

```
QVariant Component::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene()) {
        // value is the new position.
        QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
        QRectF rect = scene()->sceneRect();
        if (!rect.contains(newPos)) {
            // Keep the item inside the scene rect.
            newPos.setX(qMin(rect.right(), qMax(newPos.x(), rect.left())));
            newPos.setY(qMin(rect.bottom(), qMax(newPos.y(), rect.top())));
            return newPos;
        }
    }
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

**Note I:** You'd have to enable the `QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges` flag:

```
item->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable
               | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable
               | QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
```

**Note II:** If you only want to react on finished movement, consider using the `GraphicsItemChange` flag `ItemPositionHasChanged`